# Existe-t-il un adjectif signifiant « qui rend fier » ?

Tags: adjectifs, demande-de-mot

*Fier* est un adjectif : on peut dire « je suis fier d'*une certaine chose* ».
Mais existe-t-il un autre adjectif permettant d'inverser et de généraliser cette formulation ?

Par exemple, « être bon *rend fier* » pourrait-il donner…

> Être bon est [*??*].
>
> Il est [*??*] d'être bon.

(J'avoue que le néologisme *affiérisant* m'est venu spontanément.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

L'adjectif avec le sens le plus proche auquel je pense est « flatteur ».

Comment: “flatteur” n'a-t-il pas une consonance péjorative qui n'a pas lieu d'être ici ?

Comment: @Matti : « flatteur » *peut* laisser paraître un sentiment exagéré, ou qui touche l'orgueil. Mais ce n'est pas nécessairement péjoratif.

Comment: Après quelques jours d'essai, effectivement, c'est cet adjectif qui me semble correspondre le plus, une fois admis que le côté péjoratif n'est pas systématique  :)

Answer (score 12):

Je pense à [gratifiant](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/gratifiant) ou [valorisant](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/valorisant/adjectif), mais ils ne rendent pas vraiment la notion de fierté.

En soi, « qui rend fier » n'est peut-être pas si mal, non ?

Comment: Ces adjectifs me paraissent effectivement les plus indiqués de manière générale, puisque sans aucune ambiguïté potentiellement péjorative, mais dans cette tournure précise, j'ai fini par m'habituer au "flatteur" conseillé par Otiel  :)  Merci néanmoins Joubarc pour cet élargissement de vocabulaire !

Answer (score 4):

*Fieffé* est un synonyme de *fier*, vieilli, il est employé maintenant dans les tournures de la forme :
 *être une fieffé canaille*.

*Satisfaisant* est très sympathique, car il a la fierté sans l'orgueil et n'induit pas d'auto-satisfaction emphatique dans les phrases proposées.

*être bon est satisfaisant*, ou, *il est satisfaisant d'être bon*. 

Si la phrase s'arrête là, la satisfaction suffit, et on peut en être fier.

Answer (score 3):

"enorgueillant" pourrait peut-être convenir.

Cependant, tous les adjectifs que l'on peut proposer ne sont qu'approximatifs. Seule l'expression "rendre fier" décrit ce qu'on veut dire.

Answer (score 3):

In English there's "[prideworthy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prideworthy)," an adjective that seems to capture the idea nearly spot-on.

In French, the phrase "[digne de fierté](http://www.linguee.com/french-english/translation/digne+de+fiert%C3%A9.html)" comes close to the idea of "prideworthy," but that's a phrase and not a single-word as you are seeking.

"[Praiseworthy](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/praiseworthy)" comes fairly close to "prideworthy," and in French, a single-word translation for "praiseworthy" is "[louable](http://dictionary.reverso.net/french-english/louable)."

So

> Etre bon est louable. Et: Il est louable d'être bon.

would also come fairly close.